# Android: search results list view with images and text

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android

In the android 4.1 app I am developing, I want my text in the search results list view to appear to the right of the thumbnail. I get the results by parsing an xml file. Right now my text is appearing below the image but I want it to appear to the image's right.

people_search_list.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:contentDescription="@string/description"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="" />

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/prev_10_results"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
            android:text="@string/prev_10_results" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_10_results"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="@string/next_10_results" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

PeopleSearchAdapter.java (this is where I am displaying the content after having fetched it from an xml file)

```
    public PeopleListView (Context context, String itemName, String itemLocation, String image_url, String kudoRank)
        {
            super (context);
            setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 3, 5, 0);

            image = new ImageView (context);
            Log.v("Image URL: ", image_url);
            if(image_url != null && !(image_url.equals("")))
            {
                try
                {
                    URL url = new URL (image_url);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                    conn.connect();
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream (bis);
                    bis.close ();
                    image.setImageBitmap(bm);
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
            }
            addView (image, params);

            name = new TextView (context);
            name.setText(itemName);
            name.setTextSize(16f);
            name.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            addView(name, params);

            kudo_rank = new TextView (context);
            kudo_rank.setText(kudoRank);
            kudo_rank.setTextSize(16f);
            kudo_rank.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            addView(kudo_rank, params);

            location = new TextView (context);
            location.setText(itemLocation);
            location.setTextSize(16f);
            location.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            addView(location, params);

        }

I've attached a screenshot of how the results are being displayed now and just want the three text fields that are displayed below the image right now to be displayed to its right instead.
```

[image: search results view]

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this would be to define your layout in the `ListView` xml. Here is what I used. I did something similar with an app, hope it helps:

This is where the list view is displayed:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/view" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/logo"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="a15009789e230a7" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/background"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >
    </ListView>






</RelativeLayout>
```

This is where the `ListView` is defined, with a layout similar to what you want:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgThumb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/diningbutton"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgThumb"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/diningTitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listSubHeader"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the adapter:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.setContentView(R.layout.dining);



    // Create ListData object to hold list data
    ListData newListItem = new ListData();

    try
    {
        // parse data and populate the list view
        this.itemObject = newListItem.getData(DATAURL);
        Log.e(TAG, "item object: " + this.itemObject.toString());
        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this, R.layout.dininglistview, this.itemObject);
        // Create listview
        this.listView1 = (ListView) this.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        this.listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
        GetImagesTask imgTask = new GetImagesTask();
        imgTask.execute(this.itemObject);

        AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest re = new AdRequest();
        adView.loadAd(re);

    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {

        Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected error", e);
    }
    catch (ServiceException e)
    {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(DiningActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Temporarily unavailable");
        alertDialog.setMessage("Please contact top25@uievolution.com");
        alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // if there is an error, send the user to the home page
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(DiningActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                DiningActivity.this.startActivity(homeIntent);

            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
    // implement dining adapter

}
```

I hope this helps! Best of luck!